# Spring MVC @ModelAttribute seems to behave asynchronously (using jpa) and need it to be synchronous

Tags: java, spring, jpa, asynchronous

I need the following code to behave synchronously.

Here is the relevant part of my HomeController class

```java
    /*
     * Pulls up beancoin blockchain on startup. 
     * 
     * If no beancoin exists, create one and populate it with initial values
     */
    @ModelAttribute("blockchain")
    public Blockchain addBlockchain() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InterruptedException {
        try {
            Blockchain blockchain = blockchainApp.getBlockchainService("beancoin");
            pnapp = new PubNubApp(blockchain);
            System.out.println("Pulling up your beancoin from our records");
            return blockchain;
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            System.err.println("Creating new beancoin");
            Blockchain blockchain = blockchainApp.newBlockchainService("beancoin");
            
            // this seems to be going async and I need it to be sync (based on web render). What could be cause?
            Initializer.loadBC("beancoin");
            return blockchain;
        }
    }
```

The above works fine in terms of flow and it populates the local database properly. However, what displays on the webpage the first time is only the genesis_block and then I have to start and stop the server and then it displays all the five blocks from the `Initializer.loadBC("beancoin");` call. I don't know what part of this is causing it to be out of sync.

Here is the `Initailizer.loadBC("beancoin");` stack, as much as I think will be helpful.

calls:

```java
    public static void loadBC(String nameOfBlockchain) {
        BlockchainService blockchainApp = new BlockchainService();
        blockchainApp.addBlockService(nameOfBlockchain, new String[] { "Dance", "The", "Quickstep" });
        blockchainApp.addBlockService(nameOfBlockchain, new String[] { "Dance", "The", "Waltz" });
        blockchainApp.addBlockService(nameOfBlockchain, new String[] { "Dance", "The", "Tango" });
        blockchainApp.addBlockService(nameOfBlockchain, new String[] { "Dance", "The", "Samba" });
        blockchainApp.addBlockService(nameOfBlockchain, new String[] { "Dance", "With", "Us", "America" });
    }
```

calls:

```java
    public boolean addBlockService(String name, String[] data) {
        return blockchainD.addBlock(name, data);
    }
```

calls:

```java
    @Override
    public boolean addBlock(String name, String[] data) {
        this.connect();
        Query query = em.createQuery("select b from Blockchain b where b.instance_name = :name");
        query.setParameter("name", name);
        Blockchain blockchain = (Blockchain) query.getSingleResult();
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            Block new_block = blockchain.add_block(data);
            em.persist(new_block);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            this.disconnect();
            System.out.println("Returning true");
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I think that should be all the information you need.

It is not throwing any errors. It is simply out of sync with the page, so if I flush all the database tables (to start from scratch) and launch the server, this is what appears:

[image]

Only this.

Yet the database has everything I need and if I start and stop the server, and go to same page, I get this (as expected).

[image]

This is more than a display concern, although that matters. I need my controller to be up to date so that it can communicate with other nodes and properly report the chain and update the chain as necessary. It seems there's something in my code that implicitly tells the JVM that it can run concurrently or something on separate threads?? Please help me understand

EDIT: It seems to still behave Async when I change up the controller code to this. I'm surely giving it enough time so there must be a concept I don't understand.

```java
    @ModelAttribute("blockchain")
    public Blockchain addBlockchain() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InterruptedException {
        try {
            Blockchain blockchain = blockchainApp.getBlockchainService("beancoin");
            pnapp = new PubNubApp(blockchain);
            System.out.println("Pulling up your beancoin from our records");
            return blockchain;
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            System.err.println("Creating new beancoin");
            Blockchain blockchain = blockchainApp.newBlockchainService("beancoin");
            Thread.sleep(15000);
            // this seems to be going async and I need it to be sync (based on web render).
            // What could be cause?
            blockchainApp.addBlockService("beancoin", new String[] { "Dance", "The", "Quickstep" });
            blockchainApp.addBlockService("beancoin", new String[] { "Dance", "The", "Waltz" });
            blockchainApp.addBlockService("beancoin", new String[] { "Dance", "The", "Tango" });
            blockchainApp.addBlockService("beancoin", new String[] { "Dance", "The", "Samba" });
            blockchainApp.addBlockService("beancoin", new String[] { "Dance", "With", "Us", "America" });
            return blockchain;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm kind of an idiot and so I'm glad nobody answered this. It has nothing to do with sync or async.

Better to explain with code what I needed to do than with words:

```java
    @ModelAttribute("blockchain")
    public Blockchain addBlockchain() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InterruptedException {
        try {
            Blockchain blockchain = blockchainApp.getBlockchainService("beancoin");
            pnapp = new PubNubApp(blockchain);
            System.out.println("Pulling up your beancoin from our records");
            return blockchain;
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            System.err.println("Creating new beancoin");
            Blockchain blockchain = blockchainApp.newBlockchainService("beancoin");
            // this seems to be going async and I need it to be sync (based on web render).
            // What could be cause? Thread.sleep(15000) doesn't fix it. 
            blockchainApp.addBlockService("beancoin", new String[] { "Dance", "The", "Quickstep" });
            blockchainApp.addBlockService("beancoin", new String[] { "Dance", "The", "Waltz" });
            blockchainApp.addBlockService("beancoin", new String[] { "Dance", "The", "Tango" });
            blockchainApp.addBlockService("beancoin", new String[] { "Dance", "The", "Samba" });
            blockchainApp.addBlockService("beancoin", new String[] { "Dance", "With", "Us", "America" });
            Blockchain populated_blockchain = blockchainApp.getBlockchainService("beancoin");
            return populated_blockchain;
        }
    }
```

I was indeed adding to database each call but I was not re-querying the instance that I needed. So simple, so in a way it was async, but not due to threads or anything of that nature. Just a human oversight.